# Setup Email accounts on IIS7

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7, asp.net

I managed to setup my server to the point at which I can send emails from my application. However I would like to know how to get individual accounts setup, so I can have a123@domain.com and a456@domain.com etc and these accounts can be checked via an email application such as Thunderbird. It honestly doesn't matter so much where the users can connect to the emails (like through Google or whatever) but I do need to have emails through my domain and I need to also be able to have the application send out emails.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

IIS is not an e-mail mailbox server.  It does contain SMTP functionality which is why you can send e-mails however it does not have software built-in to allow for the receipt and storage of e-mail.  If you need that you will have to either sign-up for one of many hosted services (Google search "Hosted E-Mail") or acquire one of many installable e-mail servers.  It seems like you would be better off with a hosted service from Google or Microsoft though.

Comment: Ok, is there any particular thing I need to do in order to get my email setup through google?

Comment: It's called Google Apps: http://www.google.com/intl/en/enterprise/apps/business/pricing.html

Answer (score 0):

You can host your own email on your server using software such as [MailEnable](http://www.mailenable.com). Mailenable is also free, there are quite a few alternatives but my personal experience with it has been that it's really easy to setup and use. The benefit of hosting your own email is that you have granular control, but you need to have an idea about what you're doing. Their help and guides are quite extensive though so it comes down to how confident you are really :)